# AVPlayerViewController pops entire stack of view controllers when closed

Tags: swift, avplayerviewcontroller

I am using an AVPlayerViewController to display video content within my application. This player can be reached via a sequence of views. The sequence is embedded in a navigation view controller. The problem I have is that whenever I close the player the entire stack of view controllers is popped from the list of view controllers in the navigation controller which means that I am sent back to my home screen (however I only want to pop the AVPlayerViewController from the list and return to the screen before). I tried to find a way to override the close Button but did not find a way. Moreover I tried to push a notification and handle it in the home screen by reinitializing the entire stack of view controllers - this solution works but does not seem like the appropriate solution. I attached the class that inherits from AVPlayerViewController and the code that implements the viewController. Thankful for any hint.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

// MARK: - EduMediaVideoViewController
class EduMediaVideoViewController: AVPlayerViewController, EduMediaViewController {

    // MARK: Stored Type Properties
    weak var eduMediaDelegate: EduMediaElementDelegate?
    var videoMedia: VideoMediaElement?

    // MARK: Lifecycle Methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpVideo()
    }

    // MARK: Instance Methods
    func setContent(content: MediaElement) {
        guard let videoMedia = content as? VideoMediaElement else {
            return
        }
        self.videoMedia = videoMedia
    }

    // MARK: Private Instance Methods
    private func setUpVideo() {
        let playerItem = videoMedia?.video
        let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        self.player = player
        player.play()
    }

    private func updateVideoProgress() {
        self.eduMediaDelegate?.updateProgress(id: 1, progress: 1)
    }
}


// create an extension of AVPlayerViewController
extension EduMediaVideoViewController {
    // override 'viewWillDisappear'
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        guard let category = eduMediaDelegate?.getCategory() else {
            return
        }
        let dict = ["category": category]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .kAVDismissNotification, object: nil, userInfo: dict)
    }
}

extension Notification.Name {
    static let kAVDismissNotification = Notification.Name.init("dismissing")
}
```

The code that initializes the video controller:

```
let eduVideoViewController = EduMediaVideoViewController()
eduVideoViewController.setContent(content: mediaElement)
eduVideoViewController.eduMediaDelegate = self
navigationController?.pushViewController(eduVideoViewController, animated: false)
```

Comment: Just a comment but If I understand correctly. You are doing wrong by putting it inside UINavigationController. I think It should be a separate controller on UIWindow not in stack.

Comment: Thanks. Solved my problem. :)